# Mouse movement between screens with different screen resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, display-resolution

I'm looking for a way to resolve the scaling issues between different resolution monitors and moving the mouse between them.

When moving the mouse to the edge of the screen, it hits an invisible void instead of moving onto the next screen.

I'm using a Nvidia GTX1050Ti and the 450.66 driver.

The monitor layouts look like this (23",27",23"), (1080,2160,1080):

[image]

On Windows, I used to use [LittleBigMouse](https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse) but haven't been able to find a suitable alternative for Linux.

Comment: Could you run this command to collect graphics related info: `sudo sh -c "lsb_release -sd; dmidecode -s system-product-name; echo ==; lshw -c display; echo ==; xrandr --verbose; echo ==; cat /etx/X11/xorg.conf" | tee ~/Desktop/ubuntu-graphic-info.txt` then share `~/Desktop/ubuntu-graphic-info.txt` . Did you try reposition the screen areas?

Comment: @user.dz Results from your command: https://gist.github.com/xbenjii/f0ff1d96ba037ea7301f4878ec622ffc Repositioning the screen doesn't really work due to the different resolutions, there's always going to be dead spots.

Comment: I'd also like to keep the resolution/scaling the same, due to 4k obviously having more screen real estate.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem!
Found no solution yet; could we open a issue somewhere?